# Using groupby function with a dataframe from a .csv file and plotting the result

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, logic

Trying to Create a view of the data that generates the sum of all births for each month of each year.  need to generate a Pandas date for every row. each row contains a year value and a month value from the data in the .csv file. Add a ‘day’ column to this data frame and set the day value to 1. Then add a ‘date’ column using the year, month, and day columns.

My problem is the logic for using group by to get the sum of all births for each month of EACH YEAR . generating a pandas date for every row and having the row contain a year value, month value and then on top of that adding a day column. then need to make a 'date' column using that information and then plotting the Total Births Per month of each year.

My plot as of right now doesn't plot any data inside of it, just has framework for graph

heres my code so far:

```
     import pandas as pd
     import matplotlib
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8.0, 3.0)

     births = pd.read_csv("births.csv")
     births = births.drop(births[births.day == 99].index)
     births = births.drop(births[births.births < 500].index)
     births['day'].fillna(1, inplace=True)
     births['day'] = births['day'].astype('int32')
     births.dtypes
     births['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(births[['year','month','day']])
     print(births)

     newbirth = births[births['day'] == 31]


     start = pd.to_datetime(births['Date'].iloc[0])
     end = pd.to_datetime(newbirth['Date'].iloc[-1])

     births1 = births[births['gender'] == 'M']
     births2 = births[births['gender'] == 'F']
     births1.reset_index(inplace = True)
     births2.reset_index(inplace = True)
     births.reset_index()
     #new dataframe
     df = pd.DataFrame(births1['Date'])
     df['births'] = births1['births'] + births2['births']
     print(df)
     #newplot
     ax1 = plt.subplot(3,1,1)
     ax2 = plt.subplot(3,1,3)

     start1 = pd.to_datetime("01-01-1984")
     end1 = pd.to_datetime("12-31-1986")

     start2 = pd.to_datetime("01-01-1984")
     end2 = pd.to_datetime("12-31-1986")
     adjusted_268 = pd.Timedelta('268 days')

     ax1.plot(df['Date'],df['births'])
     ax2.plot(df['Date'],df['births'])

     ax1.set_xlim(start1, end1)
     ax1.set_ylim(8000,12000)
     ax1.set_title("Total Daily Births")
     ax1.set_ylabel("Daily Births")
     ax1.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)



     ax2.set_xlim(start2, (end2-adjusted_268))
     ax2.set_ylim(8000,12000)
     ax2.set_title("Likely Conception Dates")
     ax2.set_ylabel("Conception Events")
     ax2.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)

     #newdf needed
     #newplot needed

     new_df = births.groupby('month').sum()
     print(new_df)
     ax3 = plt.subplot()
     ax3.plot(new_df)
     ax3.set_ylim(240000,380000)
     ax3.set_title("Total Births Per Month")
     ax3.set_ylabel("Births")
     ax3.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
```

This is what the dataframe prints out as from the .csv file and after the updates I made to it using pandas

```
           year  month  day gender  births       Date
    0      1969      1    1      F    4046 1969-01-01
    1      1969      1    1      M    4440 1969-01-01
    2      1969      1    2      F    4454 1969-01-02
    3      1969      1    2      M    4548 1969-01-02
    4      1969      1    3      F    4548 1969-01-03
    5      1969      1    3      M    4994 1969-01-03
    6      1969      1    4      F    4440 1969-01-04
    7      1969      1    4      M    4520 1969-01-04
    8      1969      1    5      F    4192 1969-01-05
    9      1969      1    5      M    4198 1969-01-05
    10     1969      1    6      F    4710 1969-01-06
    11     1969      1    6      M    4850 1969-01-06
    12     1969      1    7      F    4646 1969-01-07
    13     1969      1    7      M    5092 1969-01-07
    14     1969      1    8      F    4800 1969-01-08
    15     1969      1    8      M    4934 1969-01-08
    16     1969      1    9      F    4592 1969-01-09
    17     1969      1    9      M    4842 1969-01-09
    18     1969      1   10      F    4852 1969-01-10
    19     1969      1   10      M    5190 1969-01-10
    20     1969      1   11      F    4580 1969-01-11
    21     1969      1   11      M    4598 1969-01-11
    22     1969      1   12      F    4126 1969-01-12
    23     1969      1   12      M    4324 1969-01-12
    24     1969      1   13      F    4758 1969-01-13
    25     1969      1   13      M    5076 1969-01-13
    26     1969      1   14      F    5070 1969-01-14
    27     1969      1   14      M    5296 1969-01-14
    28     1969      1   15      F    4798 1969-01-15
    29     1969      1   15      M    5096 1969-01-15
    ...     ...    ...  ...    ...     ...        ...
    15517  2007     10    1      F  180912 2007-10-01
    15518  2007     10    1      M  189157 2007-10-01
    15519  2007     11    1      F  173513 2007-11-01
    15520  2007     11    1      M  180814 2007-11-01
    15521  2007     12    1      F  173787 2007-12-01
    15522  2007     12    1      M  181426 2007-12-01
    15523  2008      1    1      F  174255 2008-01-01
    15524  2008      1    1      M  182789 2008-01-01
    15525  2008      2    1      F  165669 2008-02-01
    15526  2008      2    1      M  173434 2008-02-01
    15527  2008      3    1      F  172053 2008-03-01
    15528  2008      3    1      M  179129 2008-03-01
    15529  2008      4    1      F  169585 2008-04-01
    15530  2008      4    1      M  177399 2008-04-01
    15531  2008      5    1      F  173141 2008-05-01
    15532  2008      5    1      M  182294 2008-05-01
    15533  2008      6    1      F  169958 2008-06-01
    15534  2008      6    1      M  179267 2008-06-01
    15535  2008      7    1      F  183391 2008-07-01
    15536  2008      7    1      M  192714 2008-07-01
    15537  2008      8    1      F  182713 2008-08-01
    15538  2008      8    1      M  191315 2008-08-01
    15539  2008      9    1      F  179696 2008-09-01
    15540  2008      9    1      M  188964 2008-09-01
    15541  2008     10    1      F  175314 2008-10-01
    15542  2008     10    1      M  183219 2008-10-01
    15543  2008     11    1      F  158939 2008-11-01
    15544  2008     11    1      M  165468 2008-11-01
    15545  2008     12    1      F  173215 2008-12-01
    15546  2008     12    1      M  181235 2008-12-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Generating random data:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
rng = pd.date_range('1969-01-01', '2008-12-01', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'birth': np.random.randint(1000, size=len(rng))}, index=rng)
```

print `df`:

```
birth
1969-01-01     72
1969-01-02    370
1969-01-03    159
1969-01-04    805
1969-01-05    728
1969-01-06    190
1969-01-07    758
1969-01-08     24
1969-01-09    797
...           ...
2008-11-02    222
2008-11-03    409
2008-11-04     65
2008-11-05    451
2008-11-06    369
2008-11-07    815
2008-11-08    295
2008-11-09    232
```

Then creating the the year, month, day columns:

```
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['day'] = df.index.day
df['year'] = df.index.year
```

and grouping by year and month and finding the sum of birth:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['year', 'month'])['birth'].sum()
```

Results of the grouped df:

```
year  month
1969  1        14212
      2        14982
      3        15063
      4        12726
      5        14131
      6        16597
      7        14487
      8        12517
      9        14483
      10       17620
      11       13883
      12       17778
1970  1        15345
      2        14524
      3        18429
      4        12981
      5        16855
      6        17135
      7        18174
      8        17031
      9        14734
      10       15743
      11       12761
      12       18428
1971  1        15063
      2        17224
      3        15088
      4        17015
      5        17032
      6        17275
               ...  
2006  7        14718
      8        13212
      9        17389
      10       13850
      11       13154
      12       14126
2007  1        15762
      2        12744
      3        17176
      4        12777
      5        16254
      6        16297
      7        16038
      8        15067
      9        13724
      10       14386
      11       15701
      12       17136
2008  1        16047
      2        15094
      3        14539
      4        18662
      5        16575
      6        13553
      7        17107
      8        15824
      9        15096
      10       15139
      11       15419
      12         250
```

Now lets plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
df_grouped.unstack().plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

you can work on making the plot 'prettier' if you want

[EDIT]
I think a bar plot will look more neat:

```
df_grouped.unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: If I already have the data from a .csv file i wouldn't need to generate random data right? @Tabbakhh

Comment: How can I group the data from the .csv file/ births dataframe that I have already generated from the .csv file to use groupby to get the total births per month of each year and then add the day and Date column to that new dataframe using the groupby function

Comment: @programmernoob - You don't need to generate the random data. I just did so to produce random data that follows your dataframe's structure to walk you through the code. So begin my answer from the `df_grouped` line. 
Please have a look at the `df_grouped` results I posted, isn't this what you asked for? The groupby shows you the number of birth for every month of every year of your data. Therefore, you can not add the day to the final dataframe as all the days of each month of each year have been summed

Comment: yes thats exactly right, I needed number of birth for every month of every year. I was just confused on how to implement that with my code and wasn't sure if I needed the random generator to get that result. So all I need to do is make a new dataframe called df_grouped and do what you did above and group them together and get the sum. @Tabbakhh

Comment: also, say I didn't want it to show different colors for each month and I wanted to take that data from each month(1-12) and add that data together and plot the total births from each month into each specific year. Plotting just the year with the total from all 12 months of data. how would I do that? @Tabbakhh

Comment: @programmernoob - Sorry I did not understand what you are asking for. Do you want to plot the total number of births every year? or the total number of births in every month of your data (so you have 12 months on the x-axis and the number of births on the y axis). It would be great if you can edit your question and post a sample of the expected output.